# Two clients are trying to modify the same object at the same time and it is causing inconsistencies. How can I solve this?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, client, interpolation, multiplayer

**Game overview:**

I am building a 1v1 card game ([War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(card_game))) where player1 can flip a card, from their deck, onto the table. Once, player2 flips their card as well, the scores are evaluated and the player who placed the highest ranking card takes both cards into their deck.

**Technical explanation of card-flip feature:**

When a player flips a card, the client sends a patch request to the server, advising the server of *who* (player1 or player2) is flipping the card. The server then queries the database to locate the game state. Once the promise is returned, it updates the game state to reflect the newly flipped card and sends the updated game state to both clients.

**Issue:**

The issue arises when both players click the 'flip-card' button at the same time. Player1 will flip a card which enables the server to respond to player1 and player2 with the updated game state, reflecting the change that was made. But then, the game state gets replaced by a new game state that was the result of player2's 'flip-card' request that occurred at the same moment as player1's. And in this game state, the card flip for player1 hasn’t occurred yet. So now, player1 must click the 'flip-card' button again in order to place the card they had already placed.

**Diagnostics:**

Sorry if this sounds like parallel universe stuff, lol. My thesis is that this is occurring, because it is not possible for one client, making a request to comprehend the game state of another client who is making their own request at the same exact time.

**Technologies used:**

- [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library))
- [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)
- [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js)
- [Socket.IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO)

---

Instead of letting a client's 'flip-card' request to the server update and send an updated game state back to both clients immediately, I added a guard clause (as [*dmikester1* suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75012502/two-clients-are-trying-to-modify-the-same-object-at-the-same-time-and-it-is-caus/75076384#comment132376969_75012502)) to check that both players had indeed placed a card. Once that was verified, I sent the updated game state back to both players.

The issue with this was player1 could not see player2's card flip until both cards had been placed and vice versa. To deal with this, I implemented concepts from [client-side prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_prediction#:%7E:text=Client%2Dside%20prediction%20is%20a,actions%20on%20a%20remote%20server.) to stage temporary, local game state updates (as [mentioned by *evilmandarine*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75012502/two-clients-are-trying-to-modify-the-same-object-at-the-same-time-and-it-is-caus/75076384#comment132531214_75012502)) for both clients while they awaited the true updated game state from the server. I was not sure if it was the best method, but I tested it, and it worked.

Comment: Just commenting to mention this is a very well laid out question.   I've been doing Node/React for a few years now and programming for many more.  And I'm not even sure how to figure that out!  Following for answers.

Comment: @dmikester1 thanks, my bootcamp instructors were very big on how to ask efficient questions so props to them. 

for now, im planning to just run my flipCard() function a second time when I detect failure so that the user doesn't have to click the button again ‍♂️ 

in my research, i've came across topics like interpolation and client-side prediction that seem to be common in game dev when dealing w latency issues.

don't think they apply directly to what i'm doing here but i'm sure I can figure out a way to apply some of the concepts by thinking wisely enough.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any great ideas.  But just thinking out loud, it's like you need some sort of function in the middle that can tell if one or both players have done a card flip before passing the game state back to the clients.

Comment: okay i think thats right. if player1 flips a card, it should send a patch req to the server. but, the server won't respond until both cards have been flipped. and in the meantime, i'll have the clients place the card on their own while waiting for the server to respond with the true game state. holy crap, this might work. @dmikester1

Comment: @dmikester1 I think your idea in your comment above goes in the right direction (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

As I am also taking a shot at game development I thought I would write my input here, but please note these are just ideas and not necessarily proven concepts. Also I see you did a lot of research already. I'm not looking into multi-player games. This is much harder, as you need to deal with networking issues and distributed state and consistency, not to mention anti-cheating. So for your requirements here, I'll ignore these issues and just focus on the basic concepts that I would apply if I was doing this.

Before that, take a look at this site (the demo works better on Chrome than Firefox for some reason). This is a very nice article about client-server game architecture (although again, your requirements are much simpler):
https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-server-game-architecture.html

**Status update**
To begin with, there should be one single source of "truth" and this is almost always the server. This may seem obvious but you usually trust your server, and do not trust the clients (players). So server is responsible for maintaining state and notifying clients of changes. I'll not discuss how you should persist/store state, as it is not relevant for the question and you're already doing it in the database. The important point here is that the server cannot communicate a wrong state to clients.

*If I understand the game correctly*, state changes are triggered by card flips. But when 1st player flipped a card, game state is actually "waiting for 2nd player to play". This could (or not) be displayed to 1st player, but in any case, this "temporary" game state should not be persisted. Server is waiting for 2nd player to flip the card. 1st player is waiting. When second player flips the card, server updates the game state, persists it (in the database), and only then notifies the players, unblocking them for a new round.

**Flow diagram**
I tried to represent this in a very basic diagram with explanations below:

```
    ┌─────────┐          ┌───────┐            ┌─────────┐
    │player 1 │          │server │            │player 2 │
    └────┬────┘          └─────┬─┘            └─────┬───┘
         │                     │                    │
         │         1           │                    │
         ├────────────────────►│                    │
         │                     │                    │
         │                     │        2           │
         │                     │◄───────────────────┤
         │                     │                    │
         │         3           │        4           │
         │─────────────────────┼─────────► X        │
         │                     │                    │
         │                     │                    │
         │         5           │                    │
         ├────────────────────►│                    │
         │                     │                    │
         │                     │                    │
         │                     │        6           │
         │                     ├───────────────────►│
         │                     │                    │
         │                     │                    │
         │                     │        7           │
         │                     │◄───────────────────┤
         │                     │                    │
```

1. Player (= client) 1 flips a card. Server is now waiting for player 2 and creates a temporary state (in memory) with the result. Player 1 is not notified yet and cannot play another round.
2. Player 2 flips a card. Server updates temporary state and as all players played, persists the temporary state (which is now the current state) in the database.
3. Server sends notifications to both players with the new state. Player 1 receives it and is now free to flip another card.
4. Player 2 did not get the notification (ex. disconnected), so it is still waiting. Server will retry later.
5. In the meanwhile player 1 flips another card. Server again creates a temporary state. Player 1 is now waiting.
6. Server retry to send current state and succeeds, unblocking player 2 for the next round.
7. Player 2 flips a card => back to 2.

Of course players can play in another order and as you can see, the flow also needs to be enforced by client applications/user interface. Players should not be allowed to do whatever they want, and their UI should react to notifications from the server. You could also add a timer + ping method, logs, disconnection notification for players, etc... real fun begins when you'll ask your friends to beta test ;)

Comment: yo man thanks for sharing your thoughts. it was pretty on point with the solution i ended up implementing. just updated the post so you can check out how it was solved (:

Comment: @Anthony , if you think this is a good answer, be sure to accept it as the answer.